# How to handle routing of deprecated assets in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In our production logs we get an error like this when some IP (a bot, likely) tries to access a deprecated asset:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg")`

This isn't a big deal for us, but I'm curious what the best way to handle this is. I feel like we should be returning a 410 HTTP status, instead of the 404 it gives now. Also, would really love to get these 30 line-long error messages out of the logs.

Is there a best practice or convention in Rails for dealing with these deprecated asset routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to be done by your web-server, not Rails app.

I'm not an expect of Nginx, but you should probably add something like this:

```
location ~* /fonts/bootstrap/ {
  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }

  return 410;
}
```

[Nginx location doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) will provide more info on how to do it correctly.

Comment: Well, the biggest issue is that not necessary all the files in this folder are gone.

Comment: You can test if file exists: `if (-f $request_filename)`. If not, then send error. I've updated my answer.